# Python boto3 get item with specific non-parition-key attribute value

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries, full-table-scan

My AWS dynamoDB has `id` as `Partition key` and there is no `Sort key`. The following does not return the existing record from the table:

```
response = producttable.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('title').eq("My Product"))
```

`response['ScannedCount']` is less than the total count of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pagínate.

For example code look at https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/python/WorkingWithScans/scan_paginate.py